# mat-form-field' is not a known element in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

i am using input from angular material but i get this error
    **ERROR in src/app/modules/posts/posts.component.html:2:5 - error NG8001: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
    1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

this is my html code

```
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
     Favorite food
      <input matInput >
    </mat-form-field>


  </form>
```

this is my app module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DefaultModule } from './layouts/default/default.module';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {UserInfoService} from './services/user-info.service'
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { PostsComponent } from './modules/posts/posts.component';
import {  MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,



  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    DefaultModule,
    MatTableModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  exports: [

    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,

  ],
  providers: [UserInfoService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents:[PostsComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

i can not find the right solution for this can you help me?

Comment: wherever your component is declared (module), import your material module.

Comment: Which version of material are you using? And in which module is postComponent declared

Answer (score 4):

Add `FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,` to `imports` section. Remove both `exports` elements.

Comment: i should import them from what?

Comment: import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

Comment: Add **PostsComponent** to `declarations` too.

Comment: now i get this error PostsComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule.

Comment: Where else have you declared it? Post that too.

Comment: Please mark the answer as best answer. He gave you the answer to your exact question.