# Why can't I use Angular material components?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular 10 project, but I get a strange error using Angular material for some components, like the form-field (instead for components like "table" everything is ok):

> 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message

This is my app module:

```
...
    import { MatFormField, MatLabel } from '@angular/material/form-field';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    MatFormField
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I think need import MatInputModule instead MatFormField

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mat-form-field' is not a known element in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129859/mat-form-field-is-not-a-known-element-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the module specific to the components you will be using. In the angular material document you will see overview, API and example tabs. Select API which has the name of the module you need to use that particular component.

In your case its:

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

**Don't forget to add above module name in NgModule imports**

Better solution will be if you're using multiple material components is to create a module just for material modules and import in App.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I can't believe I couldn't see that problem. I trusted the autocomplete. My bad *facepalm*

Comment: I did this and followed the guide on their website exactly and all i get is a console full of errors. I Cannot use a single component any ideas why?

Comment: Can u please share the errors, it'll be easier to understand the issue